# Divs should overlap each other when resizing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I make 2 divs overlap each other when I resize the window?

So basically to have one div in front, the other behind, and just to keep on overlapping as I resize the window.

I want to achieve something like this example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWMpKg

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex1 {
  min-width: 500px;
  height: 538px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translateX(40px);
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.flex2 {
  min-width: 500px;
  height: 538px;
  background: grey;
  ;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translateY(40px) translateX(-50px);
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
  <div class="flex1">
  </div>
  <div class="flex2">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Use `position:absolute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.flex1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  min-width: 500px;
  height: 538px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 10;
}

.flex2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  min-width: 500px;
  height: 538px;
  background: grey;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
  <div class="flex1"></div>
  <div class="flex2"></div>
</section>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJqpVG)